# When exactly to use "assign" keyword and when to use "<=" operators?

Tags: verilog

I'm learning verilog, I have read some tutorials but i'm a bit confused about this:

When and why to use the "assign" keyword and when and why use the "<=" operators. In what context? It is clear for me the difference between "<=" and "=", being nonblocking and blocking, but beside that, some literature start by working with "assign" and others don't even use this keyword.

Example:

assign var_z = x|~y

var_z <= a + b

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`assign` is used for **driving** wire/net type declarations. Since wires change values *according to the value driving them*, whenever the operands on the **RHS** changes,the value is **evaluated** and assigned to LHS( thereby simulating a wire).

Continuous assignments drive values into the nets whenever the *right-hand side* value changes, hence **continuous assignments are always active** and assignments occur whenever the right-hand side operands changes.

**Continuous assignments** provide a models **combinational logic** at a **higher level of abstraction** than *Gate-Level* logic.

`always` is a procedural block is used for modelling **registers** and combinational logic. `always` block contains **sensitivity list**, that is, the *event list*, upon which the logic inside the block must be evaluated.

`always(@ posedge clk)` triggers the the logic inside the block at every **positive edge**. Thereby modelling a **flop** kind of behavior.

`always @ (*)` is sensitive to **all the RHS** statements. If **anything** in the RHS of the always block changes,that particular expression is evaluated and assigned. This is similar to `assign` statement, but this type of block is used to drive a `reg` datatype.

```
// var_z needs to be driven continuously
// Evaluated when any of x or y changes
assign var_z = x|~y
```

Refer to [assign statement](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/synthesis3.html) and [Continuous assignments](http://verilog.renerta.com/mobile/source/vrg00005.htm) for more information.

Coming to **blocking and non-blocking statements**:

> A **blocking statement** must be executed **before** the execution of the statements that follow it in a sequential block.
>
> N**on blocking statements** allow you to **schedule** assignments without blocking the procedural flow.

Blocking and non-blocking assignments are better understood by following example:

```
x = #10 5;   // x = 5 at time 10ns
y = #5  6;   // y = 6 at time 15ns

x <= #10 5;  // y = 6 at time 10ns
y <= #5  6;  // y = 6 at time 5ns
```

Here, in **blocking assignment**, `y` is evaluated after `x` is assigned a value. While using **non-blocking assignment**, `x` and `y` are evaluated and pushed into *simulators* internal queue and assigned at `10ns` and `5ns` respectively.

A blocking assignment effects **immediately**. A nonblocking assignment takes place at the **end of processing the current** "time delta".

So, intuitively, we can say that since **combinational blocks** needs **continuous driving**, use of **blocking statements** must be done. While, to model **sequential hardware**, that **holds or retains** a value, **non-blocking assignments** must be used.

```
// model a flop var_z
var_z <= a+b;
```

Pipeline modelling cal effectively be done by non-blocking assignments. Consider a shift register example:

```
// Improper hardware, q3 is directly assigned the value of d
always @(posedge clk) begin
q1 = d;
q2 = q1;
q3 = q2; end

// Proper hardware, q3=q2, q2=q1 and q1=d
always @(posedge clk) begin
q1 <= d;
q2 <= q1;
q3 <= q2; end
```

The above example models proper hardware while using nonblocking assignments. Refer to [CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA_rev1_2.pdf) paper, [this link](http://www.asic-world.com/tidbits/blocking.html) for more information.